# Polyline only draws 2 lines & Point.Parse issue

Tags: c#, parsing, point, polyline

Two quick questions, first why is my `Polyline` only connecting strings W, X, and Y.
Second is it possible to parse one string for multiple points, ie: store all of the numbers in string W and then `Point.Parse(W)` for all points.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string W = "0,0";
    string X = "99,99";
    string Y = " 99, 300";
    string Z = "600, 300";
    Point[] points = { Point.Parse(W), Point.Parse(X), Point.Parse(Y), Point.Parse (Z)};
    DrawLine(points);
}

private void DrawLine(Point[] points)
{
    Polyline line = new Polyline();
    PointCollection collection = new PointCollection();
    foreach (Point p in points)
    {
        collection.Add(p);
    }
    line.Points = collection;
    line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    line.StrokeThickness =3;
    myGrid.Children.Add(line);
}
```

Comment: As for the second question: you can pick a (de)serialization method for your Point[] object.

Comment: What would that look like, I can't find any good example that fit my situation. @PepitoSh

Comment: Any serialization method that can handle arrays of objects and uses text as media: xml, json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Polyline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.polyline?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Shapes.Polyline);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) connects the vertices specified with its [Points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.polyline.points?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Shapes_Polyline_Points) property, expressed in the form of a [PointCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pointcollection?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Media.PointCollection);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2).

Your current collection of `Points` defines 4 vertices, which will generate 3 connected lines:

1 line from `Point(0, 0)` to `Point(99, 99)`
1 line from `Point(99, 99)` to `Point(99, 300)`
1 line from `Point(99, 300)` to `Point(600, 300)`

Something like this:

```
\
 \
  \
   |
   |
   |____________
```

If you don't see this kind of result, your `Grid` might not have enough space to contain all the drawing, which will then be truncated.

The [PointCollection.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pointcollection.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Media_PointCollection_Parse_System_String_) method allows you to specify a string containing a collection of Points separated by a comma or pairs of `Point` references separated by a space.
These are both valid:

```
string points = "0,0,99,99,99,300,600,300";

string points = "0,0 99,99 99,300 600,300";
```

You could then have a single string containing all `Points` references.
Your code might be modified this way:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

string points = "0,0,99,99,99,300,600,300";
PointCollection collection = PointCollection.Parse(points);
DrawLine(collection);


private void DrawLine(PointCollection points)
{
    Polyline line = new Polyline();
    line.Points = points;
    line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    line.StrokeThickness = 3;
    myGrid.Children.Add(line);
}
```